# Remove an Object/Row from a Core Data Entity

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-data

There are a couple answers similar to this (Like deleting an entire entity). But none that have worked for me. I am just looking for simple way to fetch the object I want to delete using NSPredicate and then delete only that object. I only want to delete one object/row. It should be fairly simple code, nothing too complicated. I would provide my code but I am pretty sure it won't help because it isn't even close to being complete or even working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EntityToDelete *entity = (EntityToDelete *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityToDelete" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];  

NSError *error;  

[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:entity];

if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {



}
```

Comment: This didn't do the job. And wouldn't this just delete the whole entity? I need it to just delete a single row in the entity - found by a NSPredicate query.

Comment: You can add additional conditions for this object such as finding the exact object to delete entity.property = <the value which matches the object to be deleted>

Comment: Still not getting it work but I see where you are going. Thanks.